# MySQL JOIN data from tables ON similar datetimes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to `JOIN` data from two tables in a MySQL database based on similar, but not precisely equal `datetime` values. Example data set:

```
account
+-----+----------+---------------------+
| id  | balance  | created_at          |
+-----+----------+---------------------+
| 492 | 0.171248 | 2013-11-24 14:45:07 |
| 491 | 0.171248 | 2013-11-24 14:40:07 |
+-----+----------+---------------------+

+-----+-----------+---------------------+
| id  | rate      | created_at          |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+
| 267 | 802.94621 | 2013-11-24 14:45:02 |
| 266 | 802.97802 | 2013-11-24 14:40:01 |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+
```

In general, there are **usually** rows in both tables in which the `created_at` values match down to the minute, but not down to the second.

I want to `JOIN` the two tables based on the `datetime` to the nearest minute. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`account`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') as `joina`, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`values`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') as `joinv`
    FROM `account`
    INNER JOIN `values` ON `joina` = `joinv`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is sometimes the case when attempting to articulate exactly what my problem is, I stumbled upon the correct method while writing out the question:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `account`
    INNER JOIN `values` ON
        DATE_FORMAT(`account`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') = DATE_FORMAT(`values`.`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i');
```